# Are there any guides for configuring Windows to run efficiently in VirtualPC?

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtual-pc

Something like "Disable indexing" and "Disable SxS", preferably with an explanation why and guides to doing it.  I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through the archives of this blog: [Virtual PC Guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/)

He is one of the developers of VPC and now Virtual Server. Lots of good info in there, in multiple blog entries.

Comment: Ya, I know about him.  But I'm lazy.  I was hoping to avoid a hunt.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this coding horror post on [making smaller VHD's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/creating-smaller-virtual-machines.html) useful if space is a concern, or if you want a small, stripped down virtual disk image to make copies of when you want to start a new VM.

Comment: This, but for every operating system.  This won't help me much for server 2k8, for example.